# Which of the following topological spaces is obtained as the image under a continuous surjection?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, continuity

Let $X = GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of all $2\times 2$ invertible real matrices. Consider $X$ as a subset of the topological
space $M$ of all $2\times 2$ real matrices and let $X$ be given the subspace topology ($M$ is identified with ${\mathbb{R}}^4$ in
the standard way and thus becomes a topological space). Which of the following topological spaces is
obtained as the image under a continuous surjection from $X$? In each case, write Yes  if the
space is thus obtained, and No otherwise:

(a) the subspace $\{(x,1/x)\ |\ x\in \mathbb{R}, x \neq  0\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

(b) the complement in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the set $\{(x,1/x) \ | \ x \in \mathbb{R}, x \neq 0\}$.

(c) the closed disk $\{(x, y) \ | \ x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer-

Option a is yes.  Consider the map $f\bigg(\begin{bmatrix}
x_1&x_2\\x_3&x_4
\end{bmatrix}\bigg)=(x_1, x_4)$, where $x_1x_4-x_2x_3\neq 0$. This map is continuous. As the space $X$ also contains all the matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}
x&0\\0&\frac{1}{x}
\end{bmatrix}$ where $x\neq 0$. Image of these matrices is the required set.

Please help how to show that option b is no and option c is yes?

Comment: In b), we want to _avoid_ the given subset of the plane. You have made a map that explicitly hits it.

Comment: @Arthur Sorry for the typo. I have edited it.

Comment: Your option a) is wrong, as $X$ also contains the matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, which hits outside the prescribed set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) Yes, by the function $x\mapsto (\det x, 1/\det x)$

b) No, because the required set has three connected components and $X$ only has two

c) Yes, by the function
$$
x\mapsto\cases{(x_1,x_4)& if $x_1^2+x_4^2\leq 1$\\\frac{(x_1,x_4)}{x_1^2+x_4^2}& otherwise}
$$